# Mac IOKit USB signal detection

Tags: macos, usb, core-foundation, iokit

```
 matchingDict = IOServiceMatching(kIOUSBDeviceClassName); 

 numberRef = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &vendorId);  
 CFDictionarySetValue(matchingDict, CFSTR(kUSBVendorID), numberRef);  
 CFRelease(numberRef);  

 numberRef = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &deviceProductId);  
 CFDictionarySetValue(matchingDict, CFSTR(kUSBProductID), numberRef);  
 CFRelease(numberRef);  
 numberRef = NULL;  

 kr = IOServiceAddMatchingNotification(gNotifyPort,   
                                       kIOFirstMatchNotification,   
                                       matchingDict,   
                                       DeviceAdded,   
                                       NULL,  
                                       &gAddedIter);
```

For handle the notification while add the usb device to Mac pc is ok, but can i getting the signal while user press the button on the usb device?

Thanks ALL!

Comment: This has nothing to do with Cocoa, it's an IOKit question. Retagged.

Answer (score 10):

If a user presses a button on a device, this will not create a device notification. Unless this is a device Apple has a driver for (in which case you may receive an input event, e.g. an NSEvent), you will have to get the device interface and talk to that device through its interface. E.g. USB devices have interfaces, each interface has endpoints and the connections to those endpoints are labeled pipelines. There are outgoing and incoming pipelines and you can send data to or read data from those pipelines. Different kind of pipelines exist, bulk, isochronous and interrupt pipelines. Further every device has a control pipe, the only pipeline you can use bidirectionally.

Apple ships a tool named USB Prober with Xcode, have a look at your USB devices with it. E.g. my Apple Cinema Display, also connected via USB, reports the following:

```
Full Speed device @ 3 (0xFD520000): .............................................   Composite device: "Apple Cinema HD Display"
    Port Information:   0x0019
           Captive
           External Device
           Connected
           Enabled
    Device Descriptor   
        Descriptor Version Number:   0x0110
        Device Class:   0   (Composite)
        Device Subclass:   0
        Device Protocol:   0
        Device MaxPacketSize:   8
        Device VendorID/ProductID:   0x05AC/0x9223   (Apple Inc.)
        Device Version Number:   0x0114
        Number of Configurations:   1
        Manufacturer String:   1 "Apple Computer, Inc."
        Product String:   2 "Apple Cinema HD Display"
        Serial Number String:   0 (none)
    Configuration Descriptor   
        Length (and contents):   34
            Raw Descriptor (hex)    0000: 09 02 22 00 01 01 00 E0  01 09 04 00 00 01 03 00  
            Raw Descriptor (hex)    0010: 00 00 09 21 11 01 00 01  22 37 00 07 05 81 03 08  
            Raw Descriptor (hex)    0020: 00 10 
        Number of Interfaces:   1
        Configuration Value:   1
        Attributes:   0xE0 (self-powered, remote wakeup)
        MaxPower:   2 ma
        Interface #0 - HID   
            Alternate Setting   0
            Number of Endpoints   1
            Interface Class:   3   (HID)
            Interface Subclass;   0
            Interface Protocol:   0
            HID Descriptor   
                Descriptor Version Number:   0x0111
                Country Code:   0
                Descriptor Count:   1
                Descriptor 1   
                    Type:   0x22  (Report Descriptor)
                    Length (and contents):   55
                        Raw Descriptor (hex)    0000: 05 80 09 01 A1 01 15 00  26 FF 00 75 08 85 02 96  
                        Raw Descriptor (hex)    0010: 01 01 09 02 B2 02 01 05  82 95 02 85 10 09 10 B1  
                        Raw Descriptor (hex)    0020: 02 25 04 85 D6 09 D6 B1  02 25 07 85 E7 B1 02 26  
                        Raw Descriptor (hex)    0030: FF 00 85 E4 81 02 C0 
                    Parsed Report Descriptor:   
                          Usage Page    (Monitor) 
                          Usage 1 (0x1)    
                              Collection (Application)    
                                Logical Minimum.........    (0)  
                                Logical Maximum.........    (255)  
                                Report Size.............    (8)  
                                ReportID................    (2)  
                                Report Count............    (257)  
                                Usage 2 (0x2)    
                                Feature.................   (Data, Variable, Absolute, No Wrap, Linear, Preferred State, No Null Position, Nonvolatile, Buffered bytes) 
                                Usage Page    (VESA Virtual Controls) 
                                Report Count............    (2)  
                                ReportID................    (16)  
                                Usage 16 (0x10)    
                                Feature.................   (Data, Variable, Absolute, No Wrap, Linear, Preferred State, No Null Position, Nonvolatile, Bitfield) 
                                Logical Maximum.........    (4)  
                                ReportID................    (214)  
                                Usage 214 (0xd6)    
                                Feature.................   (Data, Variable, Absolute, No Wrap, Linear, Preferred State, No Null Position, Nonvolatile, Bitfield) 
                                Logical Maximum.........    (7)  
                                ReportID................    (231)  
                                Feature.................   (Data, Variable, Absolute, No Wrap, Linear, Preferred State, No Null Position, Nonvolatile, Bitfield) 
                                Logical Maximum.........    (255)  
                                ReportID................    (228)  
                                Input...................   (Data, Variable, Absolute, No Wrap, Linear, Preferred State, No Null Position, Bitfield) 
                              End Collection     
            Endpoint 0x81 - Interrupt Input   
                Address:   0x81  (IN)
                Attributes:   0x03  (Interrupt no synchronization data endpoint)
                Max Packet Size:   8
                Polling Interval:   16 ms
```

This device has one Interface, Interface #0 and there exist one endpoint on this interface (0x81), which is connected through an interrupt pipeline, that can transfer packets up to 8 bytes in size every 16 ms. If you'd now want to communicate with that pipeline, you'll have to get the USB driver interface of the device and this interface offers functions to communicate with the pipeline in question, synchronously or asynchronously, it's all pretty similar to network code.

If you now ask yourself, what this pipeline is good for at a monitor in the first place, it's how the monitor communicates button presses to the system. Apple's Cinema Displays have 3 buttons, "+" and "-" for brightness and a power button. The functionality of the power button is configurable in the system prefs, e.g. it can send the whole Mac to sleep if I want that. Whenever I hit one of those button, an interrupt event is created and sent via this USB pipe to the system (actually the system has to poll for such an event every 16 ms, but the system does that for you - your code can pretend the event was pushed by the monitor).

Have a look at the [IOUSBDeviceInterface197](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IOKit/Reference/IOUSBDeviceInterface197_reference/translated_content/IOUSBDeviceInterface197.html), and please note, that it inherits of IOUSBDeviceInterface187, which inherits of IOUSBDeviceInterface182, which again inherits of IOUSBDeviceInterface. That means if you retrieve a 197 version of the interface, all methods of the interfaces it inherits from are available for this interface as well (they are just not listed again on the page). Apple has to use interface with versions in the name to stay compatible with older code. Apple extended the USB interfaces over the time (e.g. with new OS X releases) and to be sure that old code still runs, they always added a new interfaces, otherwise they'd break existing code.

[Here you get a list](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/IOKit/_index.html) of all these interfaces. Yes, the documentation is horrible. You have to learn by try and and/or and sample code. Please note there are DeviceInterfaces and InterfaceInterfaces; that's not the same thing. A DeviceInterface is the driver interface to a device itself, every device can have multiple "USB interfaces" (this is a term of the USB standard) and the interface to such an "usb interface" is named an "InterfaceInterface". Simple devices, as the monitor shown above, only have a single interface, though.

You think that this is darn complicated? Well, most developers from other platforms say, that once they figured out how all this stuff works, Mac OS is the easiest of all platforms if you need raw access to USB pipes. However, it gets even worse: Every interface can have multiple configurations and you can set a configuration on the interface which might change the pipelines (e.g. in one configuration a pipe is a bulk pipe and in another one the very same pipe is now an isochronous pipe). You can see all this in the USB Prober application (it shows alternative configuration). And please note, that an USB device can have a completely different set of interfaces, pipelines and configurations for different speeds (e.g. one for USB 1.2, aka low + full speed, and one for USB 2, aka hi-speed).

Apple tries to explain most of the USB basics you should know before you start writing any code on [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/USBBook/USBOverview/USBOverview.html). And if you click on "Working With USB Device Interfaces", Apple even has plenty of sample code for you how to get a DeviceInterface, which you can use to get InterfaceInterfaces.

I hope I could get you some pointers and some interesting links for reading. It's not really the answer to your question, but it is a good start. Of course, you could also write a kernel driver (kernel extension) to add support for your device to the system, so that pressing the button generates an event that any software can handle without having to use IOKit at all... but I somehow doubt you want to go there.

Comment: now i can get the interface, but how to read the signal from the device while user press the button?

Comment: @rocksing: Since I have no idea what interfaces and pipelines you device has, I cannot really answer this question. How about you use the USB Prober to create a dump of the device in question like the one I have included in my answer and add it to your original question? With that information I might be able to write some code for you, that can dump all raw data the device sends to the system to console and then we can see what happen, when you press the button.

Comment: What is the meaning about create a dump in USB Prober?

Comment: USB Prober is an application of Apple's Developer Tools and a Dump is what I have quoted in my reply, starting with "Full Speed device" and so on. A device dump contains infos about this devices interfaces, configurations and pipelines. Without that, I cannot tell you how to talk to the device, since it depends on all that information.

Comment: If the device is not "Full Speed device", is "High Speed device" is any problem here??

Comment: No, it only means the device works on USB 2.0 only (and not on a USB 1.0 or 1.1 port; however all computers produced the last couple of years have USB 2.0 ports). I still need that USB prober dump if you want me to write any code for you.

Comment: Now the application can detect the device that identity by vendor & product ID. When the raw device add & remove the app can trigger, but never trigger BulkTestDeviceAdded & Removed. How can i test it? I have disable the function for download firmware, is it the reason that i cannot trigger the BulkTestDeviceAdded?

Comment: Here is the result of using USBSampleExample: Found device 0x1503
dealWithDevice: found 1 configurations
found interface: 0x1803
dealWithInterface: found 1 pipes
dealWithPipes: skipping pipe 1 because it is not a bulk pipe
found interface: 0x1807
dealWithInterface: found 0 pipes
dealWithPipes: skipping pipe 1 because it is not a bulk pipe
dealWithPipes: unable to get pipe properties for pipe 2, err = e0004061

Comment: @rocksing: Okay, I say it one more time (and this is the last time): If you expect any help, post the output of USB Prober tool and don't post it as comment, don't post it as another reply, add it to your original question. If you don't do that, nobody here can help you. There is probably everything okay with your device and we could get it working within minutes, but you are just not doing what people are asking for!

Comment: @rocksing: USB Prober is a tool, it is part of Xcode, just start it: http://img600.imageshack.us/i/usbprober1.png/ and it will look like this http://img59.imageshack.us/i/usbprober2.png/ then just go to the menu and save the USB info http://img707.imageshack.us/i/usbprober3.png/ and remove info of non relevant devices as I did in my reply above (which only contains the info of a single device). This is all I have ever been asking for. What is so hard about it?

Comment: @mecki even if rocksing didn't appreciate your well written answer, I did. I want to connect to my newly bought remote control which only ships with pc software. So figured I build the Mac software myself and you've really helped me on how to get started. Thank you!

Comment: @Mecki This is a great answer! +1 is not enough :)

Comment: @Mecki if you could help me develop my code to read the sent data that would be great! I asked my question at:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329803/figuring-out-data-from-iousbinterface-pipes)